# Edit files stored in Dropbox without downloading them to a computer?

Tags: microsoft-word, dropbox, editing

Is there any way to edit files stored in DropBox without downloading the files to my computer? I have a lot of text and Microsoft Word files stored. This seems to be possible on the Mobile App on iOS and Android. Is there any way to do it on the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, .docx, .pptx, and .xlsx files can be edited directly from [www.dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/) without any external programs. Dropbox partnered with Microsoft to provide Office Online to Dropbox users. You won't get the full functionality of the desktop suite, but its powerful enough for simple changes.

You will have to allow Office Online access to your Dropbox the first time you open a file that can be modified with the app. Once it has permission, it will open your file right in your web browser.

Please note that this is not the same Office Online as the one comes with OneDrive, meaning two people cannot edit Dropbox files at the same time.

Comment: That's great. Are there instructions somewhere?

Comment: Use this link: https://blogs.office.com/2015/04/09/office-online-and-dropbox-web-integration-now-available/

Answer (score 1):

Try this service: https://flytext.in/

It allows you to edit plain text files (not MS Word files).

Comment: Development appears to have ended in Nov 2013. Seemingly does not support IE11. Does not use [ACE](https://ace.c9.io/) which would have been a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) is a a Chrome extension which allows editing of text
  and Markdown documents stored in Dropbox, Google Drive and CouchDB. Very helpful to me is that it has a recent document list, which the aforementioned Flytext doesn't.
- If you're using Google
  Drive, another alternative is [Drive Notepad](https://drivenotepad.github.io/).